# Terminology : definition of skew for a volatility smile

Tags: implied-volatility, volatility-smile, volatility-skew, volatility-surface, skewness

Is there a generally accepted definition of skew for volatility smiles? Is skew always defined as
$$
\frac{\partial{\widehat{\sigma}(K,T)}}{\partial{K}},
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}:[0;+\infty)\times[0;+\infty)\to[0;+\infty)$ is the implied volatility surface ?

Is it typical to work with ATMF skew and not look at other strikes/moneyness points?